# escaping single quote in csv extract

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out how to escape a single quote in the extract to csv. The following string:

```
My name's Jimmy
```

shows up as this in my csv

```
My name&#x27;s Jimmy
```

Below is my code

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import loader


response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="prospects.csv"'
t = loader.get_template('accounts/prospect_extract.txt')
c = {'data': csv_data}
response.write(t.render(c))
return response
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might help, but in Django, escaping only occurs during template rendering, tell the templating engine not to escape your string: `{{ context_var|safe }}`

or you could try changing the line `response.write(t.render(c))` to

```
response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
response.write(t.render(c))
```

I also think you might have an easier time if you use the `csv` library to write on the csv file.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I can't really see how this line does anything as it doesn't provide an input to the write function that is writing the csv and it doesn't touch any variables: response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))